# Unable to install app because of error code 507 on Android Device?

Tags: android, google-play, failed-installation

Users are unable to install app from playstore with error code 507 .I am unable to reproduce this issue on devices running the same OS as my users.
This is not the error code thats generated when there is no memory on device.

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered this error was happening only for users having devices running on ARM v8 .A module was not compiled to support V8 even though the apk was generated specifically for V8 ,thus users were getting this error